# 404 errors after url rewrite with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I'm using url rewriting in my website.

I've these url:

> **works**
>       example.com/_new/app/planning
>       example.com/_new/app/user_info
>   
>   **doesn't work (404)**
>       example.com/_new/try
>       example.com/_new/features

---

Here my rules:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Removing extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

# example.com/app/[module]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^app/([^/]+)$ app.php?param1=$1 [L]

# example.com/app/[module]/[action]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^app/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ app.php?param1=$1&param2=$2 [L]

# example.com/app/[module]/[action]/[type]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^app/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ app.php?param1=$1&param2=$2&param3=$3 [L]

# example.com/app/[module]/[action]/[type]/[id]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^app/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ app.php?param1=$1&param2=$2&param3=$3&param4=$4 [L]
```

---

Here the file structure:

```
/_new/
/_new/try.php
/_new/login.php
/_new/app.php
```

The `try.php` and `index.php` should be shown as `example.com/try` or `example.com/login`.

The `app.php` loads module from another directory. This one should be:
`example.com/app/module_name`.

---

What's the problem ?

Thanks.

Comment: There is no rule to handle `/_new/<something>`, how do you think it should be handled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `htaccess`, the base URL `example.com` will be skipped in the matching, and in your file, the first regex `([^\.]+)` will match `/_new/try`  and it tries to redirect you to a file `/_new/try.php` which does not exist, hence 404.

Make sure to test your regex before trying to use the URL, you can benefit from https://regex101.com/ to make your tests.

Comment: You need to create a regex that finds your file well, I don't know your folders structure or the way you are naming your files to provide you a regex that solves your problem

Comment: Hello, I added more informations and directory structure. Is that ok for helping more now please?

Comment: move the first rule to the end of the file and you should be ok.